# "Resource not accessible by integration" when trying to create trigger

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

This is a very simple question, but after trying to find an answer for 3 hours I am asking, so I apologize if it is a duplicate.

I am trying to add a "Continuous deployment trigger" to my Azure DevOps Pipeline:

[image]

But after configuring the Branch Filters and trying to save, I get the following error message:

> "GitHub Could not create service hooks subscription Unable to
>   configure a service on the selected GitHub repository. GitHub returned
>   the error 'Resource not accessible by integration'. "

My repository is hosted on GitHub and it is private, and so is my project on Azure DevOps

I would expect this to "just work", so I really don't see which other information would be relevant on this question, so apologies in advance in case I forgot to mention something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through testing, I can reproduce this issue:

[image]

The cause of this error could be the selected service connection, when the service connection is to a `GitHub-InstallationToken`, I got the same error, as shown below:

[image]

When I choose the service connection as shown below, everything is normal:

[image]

You can check the service connections in the project settings.

Comment: Yes, I was able to do it myself by authenticating through a access token instead of grant authorization. I was going to post this as a answer but since you already did, I just marked it as accepted. Thanks!